# JavaScript function executing from browser console but not executing from Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript C# method

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a master page where I am importing a script file that has a function named `ShowNotifyErrorFor()`. This method is called from child pages that are using this master page when some error occurs during form validation. I am calling this function like this from C#:

```
double flatRate;
if (double.TryParse(flateRateTxt.Text, out flatRate) == false)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowNotifyErrorFor", "ShowNotifyErrorFor(document.getElementById('" + flateRateTxt.ClientID + "'),'Invalid Rate')", true);
    return;
}
```

When I call the same JavaScript function from Browser's console with same arguments then it is executing correctly. But it's not executing when called from C#.

The same code is working on pages that are not using any master page.

What I tried:

1. I checked if the page is rendering the form tag because one of the SO questions suggested this solution. But the form tag is being rendered.
2. I tried not to add script tags by passing `false` to `RegisterStartupScript` as the third argument. But it didn't work.
3. I checked if `ClientScript` object contains the rendered scripts and found that it has the script and I copied and pasted that script on the Browser console and it's working fine there.

Comment: Are you executing that from an Ajax call using an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @hardkoded oh thank you so much. The UpdatePanel was not enclosing the TextBox but was used somewhere in the page. But it was unnecessary to use it there. I removed it and it worked. Could you please add this as an answer with complete explanation?  It can help others in future and gain both of us some reputation points. :)